# Ajax request return empty array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I am trying to get the id, where the user clicked, and pass it to my controller via AJAX.
For some reason, when i try to show what i am receiving in my controller, it show an empty array.

Any idea why my alert return an empty Array?

JS Function:

```
function categorySelected(elem) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/newgallery/creative-fields-click",
        type: "POST",
        data: elem.id
    }).done(function (response) {
        alert(response);
    });
}
```

PHP:

```
public function creativeFieldsClickAction()
{
    $idSelected = $this->_request->getPost();
    print_r( $idSelected );
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Have  you tried to use a client like SOAP UI to query the web service and see what it returns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data should be JSON, not integer.

```
data: { elemid : elem.id }
```

Then in PHP data can be found from `$_POST['elemid']`. In your code it could be like

```
$this->_request->getPost()['elemid'];
```

Or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try by changing

**In ajax**

```
data: { id : elem.id }
```

**And in action of controller**

```
$ids =  $_POST;
print_r($ids);
```